# Returning index of nth occurrence of a substring

Tags: javascript, strings

I've built a JavaScript function returning the index of the nth occurrence of a substring in a string.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var containingString = '.this.that.';
        subString = '.';

        var index = GetIndexOfSubstring(containingString, subString, 2);

    });

    function GetIndexOfSubstring(containingString, subString, occurrenceNumberOfSubString) 
    {
        tokens = containingString.split(subString);
        var numberOfSubStrings = tokens.length - 1;

        if (occurrenceNumberOfSubString > numberOfSubStrings)
            return "Error";

        var index = 0 + occurrenceNumberOfSubString - 1;

        for(var c = 0; c < occurrenceNumberOfSubString; c++)
        {
            var i = containingString.indexOf(subString);
            var sub = containingString.substr(i + 1);
            containingString = sub;
            index += i;
        }

        return index;
    }
```

As far as I can see, the function works correctly.  Is there is an easier way to accomplish the goal? Also, can the function be improved?

Comment: Using a custom build RegExp should be faster and a lot less code.

Answer (score 13):

There's no need to split the original string or slice away at the string, you can just use the built in [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), keeping track of how many times you've looked for the substring. As a personal preference, I'd also use smaller, not as bombastic, variables names.

Also, there's absolutely no need to include jQuery in this - the `$(document).ready` is redundant.

```
function GetSubstringIndex(str, substring, n) {
    var times = 0, index = null;

    while (times < n && index !== -1) {
        index = str.indexOf(substring, index+1);
        times++;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: You should account for the length of substring: `index = str.indexOf(substring, index+substring.length);`